# python/django - why I can't call other function(in another file) in views.py

Tags: python, django

I want to call `generate_pic` from my views.py with some pass-in parameters

In views.py I have:

```
def msa_result(request, measurement_id):
    try:
        print measurement_id
        _measurement = UserMeasurements.objects.get(measurement_id=measurement_id)
        import MySQLdb
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.231.XX.XX",  localhost
                           port=3306,
                           user="XXX",  
                           passwd="XXX",  
                           db="XX")  

        print "connect database successfully"
        processing_dict = {'set_id': measurement_id }
        from post_processing import generate_pic
        result = generate_pic(db, processing_dict)
        if result=='success' :
            return render(request, 'msa_result.html', {'measurement': _measurement})
        else:
            raise Http404("Can not process image in post_processing.py")
    except:
        raise Http404("oh noooooo @msa_result")
```

The HTML page's error is "oh noooooo @msa_result" but not "Can not process image in post_processing.py"

in post_proccessing.py I have:

```
def generate_pic(db, **kwargs):
    print "I an here"  #this never print out 

    if kwargs['set_id']:
        user = kwargs.get('user', 'no_user')
        set_id = kwargs['set_id']
        set_id = int(set_id)
        return 'success'
    else:
        return "Please give a set_id to process result."
```

views.py and post_processing.py are in the same folder.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Take away that bare except clause. All you're doing is hiding whatever the problem actually is. Let Django report it to you, then you can fix it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the error is TypeError: generate_pic() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)  What should I change..

Comment: To add on what @DanielRoseman said. Wrapping large portions of code inside try-except clauses are a really bad practice. It will hide problems and make debugging a nightmare. Usually this pattern is used by people new to programming as a way to make problems "just go away".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you pass the dict into the function you have to prepend `**` to pass it in as kwargs.

```
result = generate_pic(db, **processing_dict)
```